# Matching sku to image name, using VBA, taking into consideration image number (1, 2, 3) etc?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have data columns in CSV look like this:

[image]

As you can see, first cell value **17651** has several matches, but first has to be match without underscore, meaning it's 1st of several images, the portrait (front-facing) image.

Matching all of those that don't have underscores so they at least have one image per product would be good enough, but even better if someone can figure a way to include the ascending order and create new rows so that data looks like this:

[image]

I've tried using this Dictionary code but I keep getting an error on this line **sKey = Split(Replace(arrData(i, 3)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
Dim i As Long, sKey As String, j As Long, iR As Long
Dim arrData, arrRes(), aImg
Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
'Load data
Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
arrData = rngData.Value
ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 2)
' Consolidate image by SKU
For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
    sKey = Split(Replace(arrData(i, 3), ".", "_"), "_")(0)
    If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
        objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & arrData(i, 3)
    Else
        objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 3)
    End If
Next i
iR = 0
' Loop through SKU
For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
    sKey = Replace(arrData(i, 1), " ", "")
    If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
        aImg = Split(objDic(sKey), ",")
        For j = 0 To UBound(aImg)
            iR = iR + 1
            If j = 0 Then arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = aImg(j)
        Next
    End If
Next i
' Update table
Range("A2").Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

Any VBA experts can help? I would be so grateful and will learn for next time. Is this considered a complicated VBA problem?

Data reported as table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17651 |  | 17651-2 |
| 24902 |  | 17651 |
| 25953 |  | 17651_10 |
| 26372 |  | 17651_11 |
| 26433 |  | 17651_12 |
| 26734 |  | 17651_13 |
| 26755 |  | 17651_14 |
| 26853 |  | 17651_15 |
| 27125 |  | 17651_3 |
| 27133 |  | 17651_4 |
| 27134 |  | 17651_5 |
| 27174 |  | 17651_6 |
| 27183 |  | 17651_7 |
| 27191 |  | 17651_8 |
| 27718 |  | 17651_9 |
| 27720 |  | 17651_X |
| 27729 |  | 17651-2 |
| 27736 |  | 24902 |

Picture of error:

[image]

Comment: "an error" - what error is that?

Comment: It says subscript out of range (9) - I believe answerer has correct code i just cant seem to make it work with original data format. Column A with SKu and column C with image name. Just trying to match first image with image name with no underscore since that would denote extra image which is not necesssary.

Comment: If the value you're trying to split has no content then you'll get that error message.  You may need to add code to check you're not trying to split a zero-length value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, here is a solution made via formula:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17651 |  | 17651-2 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1)=1 | =IF(E1,LEFT(C1,5)*1,"") | =IF(E1,IF(MID(C1,LEN(F1)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C1,LEN(F1)+2,99)*1),MID(C1,LEN(F1)+2,99)*1,MID(C1,LEN(F1)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G1="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F1),COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F1)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G1,">"&0,$F$1:F1,F1))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J1)=1,F1,IF(F1=OFFSET(F1,-1,0),"",F1)) | =IF(H1="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F1)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F1),COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F1)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G1,">"&0,$F$1:F1,F1))))) |
| 24902 |  | 17651 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C2,C2)=1 | =IF(E2,LEFT(C2,5)*1,"") | =IF(E2,IF(MID(C2,LEN(F2)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C2,LEN(F2)+2,99)*1),MID(C2,LEN(F2)+2,99)*1,MID(C2,LEN(F2)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G2="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F2),COUNTIF($F$1:F2,F2)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F2)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F2,F2)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G2,">"&0,$F$1:F2,F2))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J2)=1,F2,IF(F2=OFFSET(F2,-1,0),"",F2)) | =IF(H2="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F2)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F2),COUNTIF($F$1:F2,F2))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F2)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F2,F2)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G2,">"&0,$F$1:F2,F2))))) |
| 25953 |  | 17651_10 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C3,C3)=1 | =IF(E3,LEFT(C3,5)*1,"") | =IF(E3,IF(MID(C3,LEN(F3)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C3,LEN(F3)+2,99)*1),MID(C3,LEN(F3)+2,99)*1,MID(C3,LEN(F3)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G3="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F3),COUNTIF($F$1:F3,F3)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F3)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F3,F3)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G3,">"&0,$F$1:F3,F3))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J3)=1,F3,IF(F3=OFFSET(F3,-1,0),"",F3)) | =IF(H3="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F3)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F3),COUNTIF($F$1:F3,F3))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F3)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F3,F3)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G3,">"&0,$F$1:F3,F3))))) |
| 26372 |  | 17651_11 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C4,C4)=1 | =IF(E4,LEFT(C4,5)*1,"") | =IF(E4,IF(MID(C4,LEN(F4)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C4,LEN(F4)+2,99)*1),MID(C4,LEN(F4)+2,99)*1,MID(C4,LEN(F4)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G4="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F4),COUNTIF($F$1:F4,F4)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F4)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F4,F4)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G4,">"&0,$F$1:F4,F4))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J4)=1,F4,IF(F4=OFFSET(F4,-1,0),"",F4)) | =IF(H4="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F4)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F4),COUNTIF($F$1:F4,F4))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F4)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F4,F4)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G4,">"&0,$F$1:F4,F4))))) |
| 26433 |  | 17651_12 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C5,C5)=1 | =IF(E5,LEFT(C5,5)*1,"") | =IF(E5,IF(MID(C5,LEN(F5)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C5,LEN(F5)+2,99)*1),MID(C5,LEN(F5)+2,99)*1,MID(C5,LEN(F5)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G5="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F5),COUNTIF($F$1:F5,F5)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F5)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F5,F5)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G5,">"&0,$F$1:F5,F5))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J5)=1,F5,IF(F5=OFFSET(F5,-1,0),"",F5)) | =IF(H5="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F5)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F5),COUNTIF($F$1:F5,F5))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F5)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F5,F5)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G5,">"&0,$F$1:F5,F5))))) |
| 26734 |  | 17651_13 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C6,C6)=1 | =IF(E6,LEFT(C6,5)*1,"") | =IF(E6,IF(MID(C6,LEN(F6)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C6,LEN(F6)+2,99)*1),MID(C6,LEN(F6)+2,99)*1,MID(C6,LEN(F6)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G6="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F6),COUNTIF($F$1:F6,F6)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F6)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F6,F6)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G6,">"&0,$F$1:F6,F6))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J6)=1,F6,IF(F6=OFFSET(F6,-1,0),"",F6)) | =IF(H6="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F6)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F6),COUNTIF($F$1:F6,F6))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F6)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F6,F6)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G6,">"&0,$F$1:F6,F6))))) |
| 26755 |  | 17651_14 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C7,C7)=1 | =IF(E7,LEFT(C7,5)*1,"") | =IF(E7,IF(MID(C7,LEN(F7)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C7,LEN(F7)+2,99)*1),MID(C7,LEN(F7)+2,99)*1,MID(C7,LEN(F7)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G7="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F7),COUNTIF($F$1:F7,F7)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F7)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F7,F7)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G7,">"&0,$F$1:F7,F7))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J7)=1,F7,IF(F7=OFFSET(F7,-1,0),"",F7)) | =IF(H7="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F7)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F7),COUNTIF($F$1:F7,F7))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F7)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F7,F7)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G7,">"&0,$F$1:F7,F7))))) |
| 26853 |  | 17651_15 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C8,C8)=1 | =IF(E8,LEFT(C8,5)*1,"") | =IF(E8,IF(MID(C8,LEN(F8)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C8,LEN(F8)+2,99)*1),MID(C8,LEN(F8)+2,99)*1,MID(C8,LEN(F8)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G8="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F8),COUNTIF($F$1:F8,F8)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F8)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F8,F8)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G8,">"&0,$F$1:F8,F8))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J8)=1,F8,IF(F8=OFFSET(F8,-1,0),"",F8)) | =IF(H8="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F8)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F8),COUNTIF($F$1:F8,F8))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F8)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F8,F8)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G8,">"&0,$F$1:F8,F8))))) |
| 27125 |  | 17651_3 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C9,C9)=1 | =IF(E9,LEFT(C9,5)*1,"") | =IF(E9,IF(MID(C9,LEN(F9)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C9,LEN(F9)+2,99)*1),MID(C9,LEN(F9)+2,99)*1,MID(C9,LEN(F9)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G9="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F9),COUNTIF($F$1:F9,F9)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F9)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F9,F9)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G9,">"&0,$F$1:F9,F9))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J9)=1,F9,IF(F9=OFFSET(F9,-1,0),"",F9)) | =IF(H9="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F9)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F9),COUNTIF($F$1:F9,F9))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F9)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F9,F9)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G9,">"&0,$F$1:F9,F9))))) |
| 27133 |  | 17651_4 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C10,C10)=1 | =IF(E10,LEFT(C10,5)*1,"") | =IF(E10,IF(MID(C10,LEN(F10)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C10,LEN(F10)+2,99)*1),MID(C10,LEN(F10)+2,99)*1,MID(C10,LEN(F10)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G10="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F10),COUNTIF($F$1:F10,F10)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F10)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F10,F10)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G10,">"&0,$F$1:F10,F10))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J10)=1,F10,IF(F10=OFFSET(F10,-1,0),"",F10)) | =IF(H10="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F10)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F10),COUNTIF($F$1:F10,F10))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F10)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F10,F10)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G10,">"&0,$F$1:F10,F10))))) |
| 27134 |  | 17651_5 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C11,C11)=1 | =IF(E11,LEFT(C11,5)*1,"") | =IF(E11,IF(MID(C11,LEN(F11)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C11,LEN(F11)+2,99)*1),MID(C11,LEN(F11)+2,99)*1,MID(C11,LEN(F11)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G11="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F11),COUNTIF($F$1:F11,F11)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F11)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F11,F11)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G11,">"&0,$F$1:F11,F11))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J11)=1,F11,IF(F11=OFFSET(F11,-1,0),"",F11)) | =IF(H11="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F11)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F11),COUNTIF($F$1:F11,F11))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F11)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F11,F11)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G11,">"&0,$F$1:F11,F11))))) |
| 27174 |  | 17651_6 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C12,C12)=1 | =IF(E12,LEFT(C12,5)*1,"") | =IF(E12,IF(MID(C12,LEN(F12)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C12,LEN(F12)+2,99)*1),MID(C12,LEN(F12)+2,99)*1,MID(C12,LEN(F12)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G12="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F12),COUNTIF($F$1:F12,F12)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F12)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F12,F12)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G12,">"&0,$F$1:F12,F12))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J12)=1,F12,IF(F12=OFFSET(F12,-1,0),"",F12)) | =IF(H12="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F12)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F12),COUNTIF($F$1:F12,F12))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F12)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F12,F12)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G12,">"&0,$F$1:F12,F12))))) |
| 27183 |  | 17651_7 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C13,C13)=1 | =IF(E13,LEFT(C13,5)*1,"") | =IF(E13,IF(MID(C13,LEN(F13)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C13,LEN(F13)+2,99)*1),MID(C13,LEN(F13)+2,99)*1,MID(C13,LEN(F13)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G13="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F13),COUNTIF($F$1:F13,F13)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F13)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F13,F13)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G13,">"&0,$F$1:F13,F13))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J13)=1,F13,IF(F13=OFFSET(F13,-1,0),"",F13)) | =IF(H13="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F13)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F13),COUNTIF($F$1:F13,F13))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F13)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F13,F13)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G13,">"&0,$F$1:F13,F13))))) |
| 27191 |  | 17651_8 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C14,C14)=1 | =IF(E14,LEFT(C14,5)*1,"") | =IF(E14,IF(MID(C14,LEN(F14)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C14,LEN(F14)+2,99)*1),MID(C14,LEN(F14)+2,99)*1,MID(C14,LEN(F14)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G14="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F14),COUNTIF($F$1:F14,F14)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F14)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F14,F14)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G14,">"&0,$F$1:F14,F14))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J14)=1,F14,IF(F14=OFFSET(F14,-1,0),"",F14)) | =IF(H14="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F14)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F14),COUNTIF($F$1:F14,F14))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F14)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F14,F14)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G14,">"&0,$F$1:F14,F14))))) |
| 27718 |  | 17651_9 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C15,C15)=1 | =IF(E15,LEFT(C15,5)*1,"") | =IF(E15,IF(MID(C15,LEN(F15)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C15,LEN(F15)+2,99)*1),MID(C15,LEN(F15)+2,99)*1,MID(C15,LEN(F15)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G15="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F15),COUNTIF($F$1:F15,F15)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F15)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F15,F15)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G15,">"&0,$F$1:F15,F15))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J15)=1,F15,IF(F15=OFFSET(F15,-1,0),"",F15)) | =IF(H15="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F15)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F15),COUNTIF($F$1:F15,F15))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F15)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F15,F15)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G15,">"&0,$F$1:F15,F15))))) |
| 27720 |  | 17651_X |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C16,C16)=1 | =IF(E16,LEFT(C16,5)*1,"") | =IF(E16,IF(MID(C16,LEN(F16)+2,99)="",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MID(C16,LEN(F16)+2,99)*1),MID(C16,LEN(F16)+2,99)*1,MID(C16,LEN(F16)+2,99))),"") | =IF(G16="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F16),COUNTIF($F$1:F16,F16)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F16)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F16,F16)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G16,">"&0,$F$1:F16,F16))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J16)=1,F16,IF(F16=OFFSET(F16,-1,0),"",F16)) | =IF(H16="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F16)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F16),COUNTIF($F$1:F16,F16))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F16)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F16,F16)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G16,">"&0,$F$1:F16,F16))))) |
| 27729 |  | 17651-2 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C17,C17)=1 | =IF(E17,LEFT(C17,5)*1,"") | =IF(E17,IF(MID(C17,LEN(F17)+2,99)="",1,MID(C17,LEN(F17)+2,99)*1),"") | =IF(G17="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F17),COUNTIF($F$1:F17,F17)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F17)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F17,F17)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G17,">"&0,$F$1:F17,F17))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J17)=1,F17,IF(F17=OFFSET(F17,-1,0),"",F17)) | =IF(H17="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F17)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F17),COUNTIF($F$1:F17,F17))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F17)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F17,F17)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G17,">"&0,$F$1:F17,F17))))) |
| 27736 |  | 24902 |  | =COUNTIF($C$1:C18,C18)=1 | =IF(E18,LEFT(C18,5)*1,"") | =IF(E18,IF(MID(C18,LEN(F18)+2,99)="",1,MID(C18,LEN(F18)+2,99)*1),"") | =IF(G18="","",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F18),COUNTIF($F$1:F18,F18)),INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F18)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F18,F18)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G18,">"&0,$F$1:F18,F18))))) |  | =IF(ROW(J18)=1,F18,IF(F18=OFFSET(F18,-1,0),"",F18)) | =IF(H18="","",IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($F:$F=F18)/($G:$G=AGGREGATE(15,6,$G:$G/($F:$F=F18),COUNTIF($F$1:F18,F18))),1)),INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G:$G)/($F:$F=F18)/(NOT(ISNUMBER($G:$G))),COUNTIF($F$1:F18,F18)-COUNTIFS($G$1:G18,">"&0,$F$1:F18,F18))))) |

Comment: Very interesting take on this, creative as hell!

Answer (score 1):

- The data layout is changed. You have to revise the code. `Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion` doesn't catch the column C coz the column B is blank.
- An UDF is used to sort image name.
- Column E and F is the output, modify as needed

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, j As Long, iR As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), aImg
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Load data
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = Range("A1:C" & lastRow)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 2)
    ' Consolidate image by SKU
    For i = LBound(arrData) To lastRow
        If Len(arrData(i, 3)) > 0 Then
            sKey = Split(Replace(arrData(i, 3), "-", "_"), "_")(0)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & arrData(i, 3)
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    iR = 0
    ' Loop through SKU
    For i = LBound(arrData) To lastRow
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) = 0 Then Exit For
        sKey = Replace(arrData(i, 1), " ", "")
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            aImg = Split(objDic(sKey), ",")
            If UBound(aImg) > 0 Then aImg = SortArray(aImg)
            For j = 0 To UBound(aImg)
                iR = iR + 1
                If j = 0 Then arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
                arrRes(iR, 2) = aImg(j)
            Next
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update table
    Range("E1").Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub

Function SortArray(aData)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, vTmp
    For i = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aData(i) > aData(j) Then
                vTmp = aData(i)
                aData(i) = aData(j)
                aData(j) = vTmp
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    SortArray = aData
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @taller! However I'm running into this issue: **sKey = Split(Replace(arrData(i, 3), "-", "_"), "_")(0)** The results on the right work great, I just don't see why the above error is ocuring. My knowledge of VBA is outdated :(

Comment: I don't think the code is from my reply.

Comment: It is I believe, I used it in Visual studio. It's saying that's an error. What values go into the UDF?

Comment: It says subscript out of range on that same line .. ?

Comment: Why not debug the code with Excel integreted VBA Editor? Comparing with `sKey = Split(Replace(arrData(i, 3), "-", "_"), "_")(0)` , your code missed some parameters.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but whic parameters am I missing. I'm consufed because you have two separate pairs of columns, is this supposed to work with one pair in column A and C or differently?

Comment: `What values go into the UDF?` It is an array which holds the list of image name.

Comment: Sorry for hassle but I update OP to show error.

Comment: Column E and F is the output. I dont' want to overwrite the source table.

Comment: Ugh I just can't seem to make your code work. Here is pic of error: https://imgur.com/a/mkLsOQS

Comment: Is `arrData(i, 3)` empty when you get the error?  If not, what is its value?

Comment: What's the layout of your source table? Is it same as the first screenshot in your post? I saw it was in column A and `B` first, then it is changed to column A and `C`. As Tim's comment, it raises error if the cell in column C is blank.

Comment: I guess you may have blank cells in column C. Adding `If Len(sKey) > 0 Then` to avoid the error.

Comment: Ok strange, I'm receiving error when I click "Debug" on VBA Studio **Range("E1").Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes**

Comment: Here's data (if you don't mind taking a peek?) https://file.io/JVDNbRZK2XYe

Comment: The pattern of your real data is different with sampe date. The column C has more rows than column A. Please try the updated code.